# Derived widget inside a layout

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I have an object derived from `QWidget`. If I say `object->show()` it works perfectly, but I want to insert that object into a `gridLayout` of another class, also derived from `QWidget`. 
I've tried to add it with `addWidget(*widget)` like a regular `pushButton` (for ex) would work.

Comment: Do you have a question at all? This website isn't Twitter...

Comment: This sounds like how it's supposed to work. One will need a code excerpt for a useful answer. Also, what is the error after all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take a wild guess: Check the `sizePolicy()` and `sizeHint()` of your  widget. It might be that your widget is inside the layout, but resized to 0x0.

Try to `setMinimumSize()`; your widget might then appear if my guess is right.

Comment: You're right! The size was 0x0. Thanks!